# Does LOCK TABLE block replication?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, amazon-rds

I have a master and a database MySQL with the following setup:

- AWS RDS MySQL
- Version 5.7.26
- GTID enabled and strictly enforced

I have a process that does a `LOCK TABLE` over one of the tables in the read replica and locks it for up to 8 hours. Two questions that come to my mind:

- Will the read replica continue to consume the binlog from master during that time? Will it stop replicating all together or will selectively replicate only tables that aren't locked?
- If it will continue to replicate, will those changes coming through the binlog be visible to other processes reading from the table?

Comment: `LOCK TABLE` is a naughty thing to use.  Are you replicating that command?

Comment: Agree. Unfortunately, this is a piece of software that we don't control. It will do that because it needs to do a perfect copy of a table before starting to stream the DB binlog and I suppose this is the only way to guarantee that no new rows will land in the table while it's processing it

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are playing some devious tricks, the `LOCK` and `UNLOCK` will act the same on the Slave as they did on the Master, but later.

The binlog is 'consumed' in two stages:  First is copying the binlog from the Master to the relay log on the Slave.  This happens without any knowledge of what commands are in the stream.

Second is the executing of the commands from the Slave's relay log.  This happens as fast or as slow as the queries (and other things going on in the Slave) allow.

Comment: In this context, the LOCK would happen only against the replica, not the master. Basically, we have a process that reads from the replica and locks the table before doing it.